# How to deal with captcha in my drupal registration web service?

Tags: web-services, drupal, drupal-7

I created a service via the Service module on Drupal 7 that allow registration on the website. Trying it i get a message saying that captcha has not been filled. I send with my request all the required data like name, or password, or email, but i cannot send captcha for obvious reasons.
Now, the simpler solution is to disable captcha on my website but i don't really want to do it for it must be enabled for the normal 'human' registration.

So, there's a way to disable captcha for a request coming from a web service? Or whatever else is the correct way to do it, for i don't really know how to correctly use web services, so i guess i'm doing some conceptual error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to remove the captcha elements from your form(s). For example, in a [custom Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7) try this:

```
<?php
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //dpm($form);
  // Disable captcha on Services user register form.
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    if (arg(0) == 'my_services_endpoint_path') {
      unset($form['captcha']);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Use the [devel module's](http://drupal.org/project/devel) `dpm()` function to inspect the form structure and find the name of the element. The example above work's for the [captcha module](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha). If you're using [Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom), I think you can just use `unset($form['mollom']);`